# VLSC: this product can't be installed on the selected update channel

Tags: installation, microsoft-office, vlsc

I'm trying to install Office2019Standard on a Windows 10 Home PC, via VLSC. I've done this on several other computers at this organisation, using the same script. Now it doesn't work anymore.

I've downloaded the Deployment tool, created an XML script, and then executed it from Powershell with admin rights.

**office2019.xml:**

```
<Configuration>

  <Add OfficeClientEdition="64" Channel="Standard2019Volume" SourcePath="C:\VLSC">

    <Product ID="Standard2019Volume" PIDKEY="XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX" >
      <Language ID="en-us" />
      <Language ID="nl-nl" />
    </Product>
  </Add>

</Configuration>
```

**Powershell**

```
> cd \VLSC
> ./setup /configure .\office2019.xml
```

**Result**

[image: this product can't be installed on the selected update channel]

I've checked that all Office installations are removed with the following powershell command which does return nothing:

```
> Get-AppxPackage -name "Microsoft.Office.Desktop"
```

**How can I fix this problem and get Office 2019 Standard installed?**

Comment: If you switch from `Standard2019Volume` to `PerpetualVL2019` does it work?  [This](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2175298-solved-projectpro2019volume-will-not-install-on-perpetualvl2019-channel) suggested the use of the [Office Customization Tool](https://config.office.com/deploymentsettings)

Comment: Thanks. The Office Customization Tool did the trick! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Office Customization Tool](https://config.office.com/) creates a complete XML configuration file with all different settings like language and versions. After downloading this I could run the [deployment tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/deploy) and finish the installation.